# Text in a multiline text box fails to display

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, textbox

I have a Chrome extension that updates two text areas in a Web page dynamically and although the updated text displays fine in the Subject field, it doesn't appear at all in the message body.

The CSS for the textbox is as follows:

```
<div id="p-b-0" class="GPW32EMDIBB editable" g_editable="true" contenteditable="true"   
role="textbox" aria-multiline="true" aria-live="polite" aria-label="Compose a message" 
style="" value="Hello, World!" tabindex="1"><br></div>
```

Can anyone see why the text value shouldn't display?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text gets set in Google Groups, post-message body but does not display?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592263/text-gets-set-in-google-groups-post-message-body-but-does-not-display)

Comment: This wasn't a CSS issue and seems to have been resolved by [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592263/text-gets-set-in-google-groups-post-message-body-but-does-not-display/13597486#).

Answer (score 0):

That particular textbox is not actually a textbox, but a content editable div. I am guessing that your code looking for an object with a "textarea" tag.

Comment: Actually, the code looks for an object whose ID is "p-b-0": var body = document.getElementById("p-b-0"); followed by body.setAttribute("value", "Hello, World!");