# Text gets set in Google Groups, post-message body but does not display?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, textbox, contenteditable, content-script

My extension, in a content script, writes to the subject and message body of the Google Groups "New Topic" page.

The updated subject is displayed just fine; it's of input type "text", so everything is easy. The body, however, is a div representing a TextBox, and when I write to it, the update doesn't appear:

[(Click for a larger image.)

[image: Screenshot of relevant HTML]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRz5o.png)

I tried setting the focus to the field first, but that had no effect.

Comment: please show your code, how did you set textbox value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you trying to set the text? [**Show your code!**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/148310)

A typical way to ***initially*** set a `contenteditable` element is like so:

```js
var messageBody         = document.getElementById ("p-b-0");
messageBody.innerHTML   = '<p>Line 1.</p><p>Line 2.</p>';
```

---

Note that using `innerHTML` erases anything that might have been on the textbox before -- which is okay for this question's scenario.

(For more advanced changes/edits, load jQuery and use it to add/delete/replace nodes inside the edit box.  But, that is a subject for a different search and/or question.)

Comment: I was using body.setAttribute("value", bodyStr); but you're right, calling innerHTML() was what was needed. Thanks again, Brock.

Comment: You're welcome; glad to help.   PS: Congratulations on getting the upvote privilege (hint, hint). :-)